# Exclude some files on running black using pre-commit

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com, python-black

I want to configure black in pre-commit and exclude precommit from checking any migrations folder.

My pyproject.toml looks like this

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
target-version = ['py37']
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''

(
  /(
      \.eggs
    | \.git
    | \.hg
    | \.mypy_cache
    | \.tox
    | \.venv
    | _build
    | buck-out
    | build
    | dist
  )/
  | ^migrations/
'''
```

I have also configured precommit.
But on running `pre-commit run --all-files`
Black formats the migration folders also
how can I configure black

Answer (score 121):

[This issue](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/438) on the `black` issue tracker outlines your particular problem

`pre-commit` finds all the python files, then applies `pre-commit`'s exclusion, and then passes that list of files to the underlying tools (in this case `black`)

`black` currently (at the time of writing) will format all files listed on the command line -- independent of `black`'s `exclude` pattern

the suggestion is to use `pre-commit`'s exclusion (via your `.pre-commit-config.yaml`) such that those files are never passed to black at all:

```yaml
-   id: black
    exclude: ^migrations/
```

**note**: unlike black, pre-commit will only ever lint files which are checked into your git repository, so the laundry list of exclusion is unnecessary here (`.git` / `.mypy_cache` / etc.)

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of `pre-commit`

Comment: dumb question but, how do I exclude multiple directories

Comment: @JamM.HernandezQuiceno `exclude` is a regular expression, so you'd use `|` -- for example: `exclude: ^(migrations/|other/folder/)` -- more on this [in the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks! This works also well for `pydocstyle`

Comment: @AnthonySottile request you add this example to the docs. I tried the regex approach (?x)^(...) for a mix of files and folders and couldn't get it working. I found your answer here and it worked like a charm.

Comment: it is in the docs: https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions

Comment: I'm getting "did not find expected '-' indicator" when trying to do exactly as you did in my .pre-commit-config.yaml

Comment: @allinws sounds like you made invalid yaml -- I can't help without seeing the full file though and could only guess at the many ways you can make invalid yaml

Comment: It would be a helluva lot nicer if `exclude` allowed globs or a YAML list of paths.

Comment: globs are less powerful, and lists are ambiguous -- so no it would not be "nicer" -- it would be more complex, and more confusing

Comment: No, lists are not "ambiguous". And no it would not be confusing. The actual thing that is more confusing is requiring multi-lined regexes to specify multiple, well-defined paths.

Comment: I'm in favor of simplicity over complexity--requiring someone to know special non-Yaml syntax inside of a Yaml file for something that could be very easily accomplished with a Yaml list, is the very definition of complexity.

Comment: It looks like you had an opportunity to improve the `excludes` syntax with pre-commit/pre-commit#591, but sadly you rejected it in favor of more complex syntax.

Comment: lists are ambigious -- is it "and" or "or" -- as someone who has spent literal years thinking about these problems please trust that you do not know what you're talking about.  also there is no "non-yaml" syntax -- there is no extension of the parser whatsoever.  there is *one way to do things* and that is best.

Answer (score 11):

Currently, you can use `black` option `--force-exclude`. As indicated in the [documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#configuration-format):

> --force-exclude TEXT            Like --exclude, but files and directories
> matching this regex will be excluded even
> when they are passed explicitly as
> arguments.

So, in your `pyproject.toml` change `exclude` to `force-exclude`.